# Cycle between views with navigation controller

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

So i want to cycle though different views controllers with a navigation controller but at the same time i want to be able to cycle back to any of the views without having to push a new instance.

The Red view is always the initial one, the user will go there after clicking in a button that is in another part of the project.

For example:

B = Blue. Red = Red G = Green.

R > Y > B.

If i go back to the Red view i dont want to create a new instance of the view, i want to retrieve the view that is in the navigation stack.

I can already retrieve what views are in the Navigation Controller with

```
if let viewControllers = navigationController?.viewControllers {
    for viewController in viewControllers {
        if viewController is RedViewController {

          print("Already initialized")

        }
    }
}
```

For now im doing

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: false)
```

but its always creating a new instance of that view.

My question is: it is possible to show a specific view that is already initialized and inside a navigation view controller?

I couldn't take a good picture but imagine that the red view is embedded in a navigation controller.

[image]

Comment: What's the reason you want to use the same instance? Generally, you'd keep the data in memory needed to set the view controller up in the same state, rather than keep the entire view controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use setViewControllers() to change the state of the stack from one set of view controllers to another i.e.

```
let viewController = navigationController?.viewControllers
// remove unneeded view controllers from the stack
_ = navigationController?.setViewControllers(viewControllers, animated: true)
```

In your example when you get the stack array it will contain R, Y and B, you can therefore remove Y and B to display the original R view controller.

---

Another way to keep view controllers permanently loaded is to create a parent view controller that contains 3 container views layered one on top of the other.
(maybe you need to read up and experiment with container views, it is a view that has a view controller embedded within it).Each of the container views has one of your R, Y or B view controllers embedded within it.
You switch between the 3 view controllers by changing the alpha of the container views.

i.e. to display the R view controller, the R container's view's alpha is set to 1.0 with the Y and B's container views' alpha is set to 0.0

Comment: The problem is, lets suppose i have a json in the 3 views, if i simple remove the views i'll have to load the json again if i call the views, i want to save the state of the view so i don't need to do that.

Comment: Create the three view controllers as member variables of a class (i.e. a controller controller type of class) then they will be instantiated and loaded once, then add and remove the view controllers to the array that is passed to setViewControllers. You will have to always call setViewControllers rather than push and pop etc. Seems a lot of effect, is it worth it? Whats the problem with reloading the json into the views each time? (unless its so much json the view controllers are scroll views that scroll for hundreds of pages)

Comment: Those 3 buttons are going to be a part of a Menu that will have for example Airplanes, Buses and Boats. Inside each view i'll have for example the Airplanes travels, buses travels and boats travels. I expect the user to change views more than once so i would prefer to avoid having to load the json a lot.

The question is, doing this is accepted by Apple? Because if not how can you change views without loosing the data?

Comment: How will Apple know or care how you are populating the views? As long as it doesn't take a whopping huge delay each time there's no problem. But maybe if the user is going to flip back and forth then maybe a tab bar is a more appropriate design for your gui  navigation? And the answer to how to change views without loosing data is as per my previous comment, the view controllers need to remain permanently instantiated.

Comment: The question is i already have a tab bar but one of the views of the tab bar will have this 3 views. Thats why i can't use a tab bar. Hahaha but thanks a lot Essence i'll implement your way but try to find a better way anyway. I mean accepted as a reasonable solution.

Comment: @gusfat Another easier way to keep the view controllers permanently loaded is to have 3 container views within a single parent view controller, I'll update the answer with further details.

Comment: Thats a good way and the memory use would be the same haha. Thanks for all the help chicken.